# KeyboardView error in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

Keyboard View in my Layout issues Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class .

in xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout>
 ///
         <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
 ///
</RelativeLayout>
```

Details:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: audio
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:602)
at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.<init>(KeyboardView.java:359)
at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.<init>(KeyboardView.java:263)
at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.<init>(KeyboardView.java:259)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Changes of API versions in Editor don't help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Unsupported Service: audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090629/android-unsupported-service-audio)